# Plagiarism on an Affidavit?

Tags: contract-law, canada, state-university

Is there such thing as plagiarism on an Affidavit? In other words if my reasoning for a certain issue is best worded by an online source, can I simply copy the source and slightly customize it to my circumstance? Would this be a problem simply because it's not completely original?

To be clear, my reasoning is the same; it's simply that I don't see a need to rewrite the work.

In case the info is relevant, it's reasoning for an exemption at my place of work. It's a large company planning to mandate vaccines with the exception of certain cases (like mine).

Comment: Good question.   I'd be interested in answers under U.S. law as well.

Comment: Plagiarism is not really a legal concept, it is a concept of ethics. What kind of legal problems do you envision from your plagiarism?

Comment: @JörgWMittag I would not expect any. But you never know with bureaucracies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> can I simply copy the source and slightly customize it to my circumstance?

Yes. Many people have the misconception that originality in and of itself triggers copyright protections. In reality, originality is only a *requirement* for copyright protection, a protection that is intended only for a roughly defined range of purposes.

[Section 5](https://laws-lois.justice.gc.ca/eng/acts/C-42/page-3.html#docCont) of the Canada Copyright Act protects "*every original literary, dramatic, musical and artistic work [meeting at least one of a list of conditions]*", this phrase referring to "*every original production in the literary, scientific or artistic domain*" (see [section 2](https://laws-lois.justice.gc.ca/eng/acts/C-42/page-1.html#h-102546)). The purpose of affidavits is not literary, scientific, dramatic, or artistic.

Similarly, under U.S. law the primary purpose of copyright law is "*To promote the Progress of Science and useful Arts, [...] to stimulate artistic creativity for the general public good*", [*Fogerty v. Fantasy, Inc.*, 510 U.S. 517, 526 (1994)](https://www.leagle.com/decision/19941027510us51711001) (citations omitted). The production of affidavits are not for the sake of artistic creativity, and usually not for the public good.

More generally, homogeneity in the drafting of legal documents (including affidavits) tends to streamline the administration of "justice". It helps the court to focus on the central issue instead of having to delve in what subtleties could arise from the particularities of how each variation is worded.

Comment: The question is about plagiarism, not about copyright, though.

Comment: @JörgWMittag "*The question is about plagiarism, not about copyright, though.*" For it to constitute plagiarism, the copied material would have to be copyrightable or involve contexts where it would be fraudulent (example: school assignment) and which do not apply to the OP's scenario. Furthermore, the OP's concern is about his copying "*be[ing] a problem simply because it's not completely original*" rather than about failing to give attribution.

Comment: @IñakiViggers Would it be a problem if I did not give attribution?

Comment: @Awsome_user "*Would it be a problem if I did not give attribution?*" Not at all. The relevance of an affidavit is all about the veracity of facts the affiant declares. It has nothing to do with [clarifying] who came up first with that particular way of expressing those facts.